# Project Utility Jar is not being added while generating EAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am using eclipse to build the EAR of my project. So I have various module and several utility jar in my application deployment descriptor(refer fig 1[image]). Now my problem is when I am trying to export the EAR using eclipse, the EAR file is properly containing the content of Module but Project utility jar is not being exported(look at the size of jar file in ear which is 181 bytes [image]). Could you please suggest me how can I achieve that.What do I need to modified so that utility jar exported properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer to my question after head crunching research. The problem with my application was the corrupted value in the "org.eclipse.wst.common.component" file. Which can be found in the .setting folder of you project. The above mentioned file had the duplicate entry for the same project. So default process was getting confused which path to include. I have manually removed the duplicate entry and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the MANIFEST.MF file of the EAR project to add the utility JARs

Comment: my EAR project doesn't have MANIFEST.MF file ... shall I create a new one

Comment: generated MANIFEST.MF have entry for utility jar